# #1142 - INSERT command denied to user ___ for table ___

Tags: mysql, insert, privileges, sql-grant

Apparently this is usually to do with size, but I only have one table with six columns.

The only thing that has changed recently is that today I installed a forum but I've removed it again and the problem persists.

I am entering the SQL manually in PHPmyAdmin.

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Could it be that vBulletin changes the permissions of the user?

Comment: Have a look at this it solved my problem may your too https://stackoverflow.com/a/46151304/5783617

Answer (score 9):

I just faced that ERROR, and found that my QUERY state incorrect spelled DATABASE name. :(

Answer (score 6):

The problem is about the user session cookies, so all you need to do is to delete those cookies by clicking on the icon at the top right below phpMyAdmin as mentioned in this mage:

[image: this image]

Answer (score 2):

Your user doesn't have **INSERT privilege.** Check user database privileges.

Maybe you changed user, maybe you just changed the HOST or the IP from where you are connecting.

Use this statement to grant the privilege.

```
GRANT INSERT ON databaseName TO 'user'@'66.40.52.21'
```

Comment: It DID say 'user'@'66.40.52.21' - how can I set it back to what it was if it's changed, and how do I check db privileges.

Comment: GRANT statement. GRANT INSERT ON databaseName TO 'user'@'66.40.52.21'

Comment: #1142 - INSERT,GRANT command denied to 'user'@'66.40.52.21' for table 'table'

How can my privileges be so messed up?!

Comment: You have to GRANT from the root user. It is logical you can't grant privilege to yourself.

Comment: To my knowledge I only have one user, or is the root user created by default?

Comment: If you are using hosting, message your hosting provider, he'll grant you that privilege.