# SELECT denied FOR table with column priviligies

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to add a user with permissions to view only certain columns in a table.

When trying to access that table from phpMyadmin i get `#1142 - SELECT command denied to user 'fhg-stats'@'localhost' for table 'rk_upd'` error

But if I query the table using SQL like `SELECT col1, col2 FROM table` i do see the correct result. So obviously I do have privileges to see the wanted columns.

But why can't i just view the table direct in phpMyadmin?

**EDIT**
`flush privileges` doesn't make any difference. 
Also the problem persists even from other clients than phpmyadmin

Comment: Any change if you run `flush privileges`

Comment: Sadly no. still #1142

Comment: phpmyadmin can be buggy upgrade to the latest version

Comment: i'm not able to upgrade at this moment, no other work around?

Comment: Or try a different client to rule out bugs like heidisql

Comment: I tried using CODA, same error. seems related to that the `SELECT * FROM table` is not allowed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424797/1142-select-command-denied-to-user-localhost-for-table-pma-table-uipref