# "#1142 SELECT command denied to user ' '@'localhost' for table pma_tracking"?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

In Xampp phpMyAdmin, when I click on database name I'm getting an error

> "#1142 SELECT command denied to user ' '@'localhost' for table pma_tracking".

What should I do in-order to rectify this error? I am using Windows 10.

Comment: check your permissions to DB user.

Comment: Global Privileges is set to all privileges

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424797/1142-select-command-denied-to-user-localhost-for-table-pma-table-uipref/18428475

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#1142 - SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'pma\_table\_uiprefs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424797/1142-select-command-denied-to-user-localhost-for-table-pma-table-uipref)

Comment: That solved my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 29):

[image]

Click on this. That will fix the issue.

Answer (score 8):

try to change address from localhost to 127.0.0.1

Comment: The original poster was able to solve the problem quite a while ago.  How does this change that answer?

Comment: This helped me. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this and the problem is fixed, can you tell me where the problem is? why when using 'localhost' the problem persists?

Answer (score 1):

1. I opened xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php file and found the following lines:

   `/* User for advanced features */\\`

   `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';`

   `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';`
2. Then I observed in phpmyadmin the following tables:

   `DATABASE: phpmyadmin`

   `TABLES: pma_bookmark pma_column_info pma_designer_coords pma_history pma_pdf_pages pma_recent pma_relation pma_table_coords pma_table_info pma_table_uiprefs pma_tracking pma_userconfig`
3. I run this sql statement:

   `GRANT SELECT , INSERT , UPDATE , DELETE ON phpmyadmin.* TO`pma`@`localhost`IDENTIFIED BY  ''`